# Flutter Positioning a widget with an expanding TextField

Tags: flutter

**Note:** just realized the container and the background are similar shades, sorry about that!

I have the following text fields:[image]

I'm trying to keep the 'Title' & 'Decsription' text fields anchored to the top of the container, however, whenever my description expands, my 'Description' text widget moves to the center of the container rather than staying at the top.

Here's my code:

```html
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 5),
                child: Row(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      // element name
                      name,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    // element widget
                    Expanded(child: widget),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(
                thickness: 1.5,
                color: Color.fromARGB(60, 105, 105, 105),
                height: 0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

I figuered I could use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` inside of my Row, but I get this result:

[image]

As you can see, the text & text field aren't vertically aligned!
I don't want to wrap my text with a SizedBox because then I'd have to reconfigure it when the font size changes..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your current snippet only containts name filed

Comment: The text field is the 'widget' property. It's a simple TextField

Comment: try below post, if fails, consider including full sample snippet from scaffold body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing seems to be related to the default padding that `TextField`s have.

This is the output layout I have achieved, and I believe it to be what you want:

[image: target layout]

See the following `Widget.build` method (commented code):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// Define common properties to easily apply them to different components.
  const style = TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0);
  const separator = SizedBox(width: 16.0);
  const textAlign = TextAlign.right;

  const textFieldDecoration = InputDecoration(
    hintStyle: style,

    /// IMPORTANT: We remove the default TextField padding.
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    border: InputBorder.none,
  );

  /// Dynamically get the size of the largest label in order to properly align
  /// based on the widest label.
  ///
  /// Note that we pass the [style] that we will use to properly calculate the
  /// size.
  ///
  /// This is useful if you use localized text, as it will allow proper
  /// layout/alignment.
  /// Example: [localization.title, localization.description].map(...)
  final maxLabelWidth = ["Title", "Description"]
        .map((e) => e.intrinsicSize(context: context, style: style).width)
        .reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);

  return Column(
    /// The column should occupy as much horizontal space as possible.
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          /// Our first label is wrapped with our determined max label width.
          SizedBox(
            width: maxLabelWidth,
            child: const Text("Title", textAlign: textAlign, style: style),
          ),
          separator,
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: textFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: "Required"),
              style: style,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Divider(height: 24.0),
      Row(
        /// You had it right, we must align to the start.
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: maxLabelWidth,
            child: const Text(
              "Description",
              textAlign: textAlign,
              style: style,
            ),
          ),
          separator,
          const Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: textFieldDecoration,
              style: style,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              maxLines: null,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Implementation of the `intrinsicSize` function:

```
Size intrinsicSize({
  BuildContext? context,
  double maxWidth = double.infinity,
  int? maxLines,
  TextStyle? style,
}) {
  final double textScaleFactor;
  final TextDirection textDirection;

  if (context == null) {
    textScaleFactor = 1.0;
    textDirection = TextDirection.ltr;
  } else {
    textScaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
    textDirection = Directionality.of(context);
  }

  return (TextPainter(
    text: TextSpan(text: this, style: style),
    textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
    textDirection: textDirection,
    maxLines: maxLines,
  )..layout(maxWidth: maxWidth))
      .size;
}
```